Movie with a man, woman and two kids in a world where most of the human race has died
This movie is form the 80s or early 90s. I think it maybe Made-for-TV.
Basically most of the human race has died, and there's just one guy, his wife or girlfriend and two kids (who I think aren't actually their kids and they meet in the midst of the disaster). 
In the end one of the kids (the boy) asks the guy if he can have a football, and the guy says "you can have the whole stadium!" or something like that (because everyone else is dead). 
At one point the guy is actually captured by the government or someone and they are performing experiments on him or something.

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

Sounds like Night of the Comet (1984). Most people are killed, some turn in to zombies, and a small number survive unharmed. The plot revolves around teenagers who survive and are captured by scientists but escape.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Comet
The Football quote:

I forgot my football.
  - We'll get you another football.
  - We'll get you a stadium.

(http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=night-of-the-comet)
